# Dynamic ViewModel Generation in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am attempting something very ambitious on asp.net MVC 3 backed with C sharp 4.0 . Without further trash talk I will get 
to point  .

I have to build a web application in which I can make simple forms ( a CMS type application) .

The usual approach we take is to design the form in the cshtml , and back it with a viewmodel.

The viewmodel takes care of the validation rules , the error messages etc. Now what I have to do is to allow the user 
to create a form .

I sat to write down on a piece of paper on how would i go about this . I would be able to generate a form , based on 
some user inputs , but where I have reached a deadend is , how would i create a viewmodel at runtime ?

for example if in my database , I konw that a form called "Registration" , has a control "TextBox" , that would take a String
and is Required

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
[Required(ErrorMessage="Cant let this go buddy")]
public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

I wish to strongly type my views with such viewmodels , but I am not sure how to dynamically construct a C# class based on some data that I have inside the database.

I am not so sure if C# has some constructs to achieve the purpose , I am just new with the .net platform .

I want to know if there is any approach by which I can generate some viewmodels from the database at runtime , and strongly type my views with them .

Thanks

Comment: You should use dynamics in your case.

Comment: You're new to .Net and your goal is to write a CMS? that sounds wrong, If I were you - I'd check out Microsoft Lightswtich before I start that adventure..

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [AssemblyBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.aspx) class that you can use for runtime types.